# What is does the syntax [/ ] mean in a C# string

Tags: c#, syntax

I am not able to google for as, as Google blocks out symbols.

it appeared in this context:

```
Console.WriteLine("Usage: findduplicatefiles [/sub] DirectoryName [DirectoryName]...");
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"[/" in a string doesn't mean anything to C#.  It just writes those characters out.  But I think you are confused about the meaning of what is being written out.

There is a convention when documenting command-line programs where putting an argument in square braces means the argument is optional.  Thus, the string your program is writing out indicates that the command `findduplicatefiles` may optionally have an argument `/sub` after which it must have at least one directory name, and may optionally have other directory names.

Answer (score 10):

It doesn't mean anything in C#. All that `Console.WriteLine()` call does is write this string:

```
"Usage: findduplicatefiles [/sub] DirectoryName [DirectoryName]..."
```

into the console as output.

However, in the Windows command line, `/` functions as a command-line argument delimiter, and `[]` means it's an optional argument. The usage prompt is telling the user that `sub` is an optional argument to use with the `findduplicatefiles` program.

Examples:

- Run `findduplicatefiles.exe` against the current directory:

  ```
  C:\>findduplicatefiles .
  ```
- Run `findduplicatefiles.exe` against the current directory with the `sub` argument:

  ```
  C:\>findduplicatefiles /sub .
  ```
- Run `findduplicatefiles.exe` against two directories, `C:\abc` and `C:\def`, with the `sub` argument:

  ```
  C:\>findduplicatefiles /sub abc def
  ```

Answer (score 1):

In this case is does not mean anything to C#. It's just a character in the string just like the rest of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Means optionally put `/sub` before directoryName. It is not a C# question.